# fusiontables limits

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Do the following fusiontables size limits still apply to private tables created by google maps premir customers?

1) 250 MB size limit
2) 500 vertices per tile limit
3) Only the first 100K shapes will be rendered

Thank You,
Vish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you purchased with your Maps Premier agreement.  But this is the default unless you specifically purchased additional quota.